# Caret overlaps placeholder and wpcf7 email input is automatically indented

Tags: css, wordpress, mobile, mailchimp, text-indent

My wordpress website which I am curently working on https://atlanticattire.com/contact/ includes a contact page which includes shortcode from contact form 7. When I do not add a text-indent code to the email field it is automatically preset out 5px and if I do -3px or so it actually disappears before getting to the edge of the from border. I added text-indent to the others but the email field is slightly unparralel with the others and I want to know how to get rid of that automatic indent. Secondly on safari the text area which says "message" does not work correctly as the caret overlaps the placeholder text.
My custom CSS is:

```
/* Contact Form Styling */
.wpcf7
{
border-radius: 4px;
}

/*Webkit Placeholder Text Styles*/
::-webkit-input-placeholder { /* WebKit browsers */
color: #000000 !important;
opacity: 1;
}

:-moz-placeholder { /* Mozilla Firefox 4 to 18 */
color: #000000 !important;
opacity: 1;
}

::-moz-placeholder { /* Mozilla Firefox 19+ */
color: #000000 !important;
opacity: 1;
}

:-ms-input-placeholder { /* Internet Explorer 10+ */
color: #000000 !important;
opacity: 1;
}

.wpcf7 input[type=submit]{
border-radius: 0px;
color:#000;
}

.wpcf7 label {
padding: 0 0 0px 0;
font-size: 20px;
color: #000000 !important;
}

.wpcf7 input[type=email]
{
text-indent: 0.0em !important;
}

.wpcf7 input[type=text], .wpcf7 input[type=email], .wpcf7 
input[type=url], 
.wpcf7 input[type=tel], .wpcf7 input[type=message] {
border-radius: 4px;
background-color: #fff;
color: #000000 !important;
border: 1px solid black !important;
text-indent: 0.6em;
}

.wpcf7 textarea 
{
border-radius: 4px;
background-color: #fff;
color: #000000 !important;
border: 1px solid black !important;
text-indent: 0.6em !important;
}
```

Sorry if any of this doesn't make any sense, any help would be greatly appreciated (: